Marie Curie postdoc fellowship - civil servant
Is it possible to undertake a Marie Curie postdoctoral fellowship while being a civil servant (taking unpaid leave)? Are there any relevant restrictions from the MSCA funding scheme? Thank you!

The legal status of civil servants depends greatly on the country. I don't think it will be possible to give a comprehensive answer to the question as asked.

@TimRias I think a specification of the country in an edit resolves that, however.

The specifics of your question almost certainly depend on the country you're in, but in general: If you are granted unpaid leave, you can do pretty much whatever you want during that time -- travel the world, sit on the beach, or take another job (like a postdoc fellowship). Generally speaking, also, if you take another job during that time, your employer will not care that you have another job that you are on leave from because you, at that time, do not in fact have another job -- nobody pays you to do anything besides the job you have taken during your leave. As a consequence, I don't think that the organization that hands out the Marie Curie fellowships cares one way or the other.
The relevant question for you -- though that's not what you explicitly ask -- is: Will your employer be willing to give you a couple of years of unpaid leave so that you can do a meaningful postdoc? Why would they let you go on leave and keep the job available to you if your goal is to take a postdoc that in all likelihood will qualify you for jobs that are better than you currently have? Why would you go back to your current job? What benefit would your current employer have from keeping the job open for you for all of that time?
